# sample size for metric survey data

Tags: sample-size

I currently read this paper 
http://www.opalco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Reading-Sample-Size.pdf

and try to understand sample size calculation.
This paper presents Cochran's formular:

```
        t^2 * s^2
   n = ------------
           d^2
```

It also provides an example for a 7-point-scaled item.
The margin of errors should be 0.03.
The standard deviation for this item is calculated by  `7/6 = 1.167`
and `d` is `7 * 0.03 = 0.21`

This leads to:

```
    1.96^2 * 1.167^2  
n = ----------------  = 118
      (7 * 0.03)^2
```

I understand this so far....

**My question is:**
Let's say my population was 70,000 nurses,
and I want to asses their age in years.
I estimated age to have a sd of 5.1 years.
I want my margin of error to be 3%

If I fill this numbers into the formular:

```
       t² * s²
n = -------------
         d²

      1.96² * 5.1²
=   --------------
        0.03²


        99.92
=   ---------------
       0.0009


=  111,022.22
```

which seems to be much to big.
I think I am doing something wrong in setting d = 0.03

Could someone please point out where my error of thinking is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, $d$ is an absolute deviation (not a relative one in percentage).
Thus, $N$ is computed so that you have a $95$% interval of $\pm0.03 years$ which is quite narrow.

If you still want to use an error percentage, you can (as you suggest in comments) use an estimate of your mean and multiply by your error margin. But I would rather suggest to take a pessimistic estimate, like 55 years, so that you won't get a real margin error which is bigger than what you planned.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So, in order to get a margin of errors of 3%, what should I do? Do I need to know/estimate the mean age, and then multiply this with my desried 0.03? Or do I need to know the span of years (maybe from 18 to 65 = 47, and then multiply this with 0.03 ?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea, I edited my post to give some precisions.